# change use-package indentation

Tags: indentation, use-package

I'd like to change `use-package`'s indentation style to look more distinguishable, (more or less) similar like the following indentation style:

```
(use-package foo
  :commands (gah)
  :init (setq f 1)
        (blubb g 2)

  :config
    (blah h 3)
    (moo i 4))
```

This means, keywords should be indented normal but all following options to such a keyword, should be indented a bit more and should align vertically.

---

I already know, that it is possible to define a function to calculate the current indentation column. Per default it is set to standard `defun` indentation:

```
(get 'use-package 'lisp-indent-function)
; → defun
```

The following function definition and set up of property, changes that, but I struggle with the implementation details of function `my-use-package-indent-function`.

```
(defun my-use-package-indent-function (indent-point state)
  (let* ((normal-indent (current-column))
        (indent-offset (progn (back-to-indentation)
                              (current-column))))
    (goto-char indent-point)
    (back-to-indentation)
    (if (eq ?: (char-after))
        (+ indent-offset 2)
      (+ indent-offset 5))))
(put 'use-package 'lisp-indent-function #'my-use-package-indent-function)
```

Above is a naive, incomplete version, but how to calculate the indentation value properly?

Answer (score 2):

Since no one came up with an answer, I stepped with the debugger through the process of indenting and came up with following code.

```
(defun my--use-package-indent-function (indent-point state)
  "custom indentation rules for use-package s-exps.

`;;!' indents to same level as keywords
for some reason `;;;' won't be indented at all"
  (let ((indent-offset (progn (back-to-indentation)
                              (current-column))))
    (goto-char indent-point)
    (back-to-indentation)
    (cond ((eq ?: (char-after))
           (+ indent-offset 2))
          ((and (eq ?\; (char-after)) (eq ?! (char-after (+ (point) 2))))
           (+ indent-offset 2))
          ((eq ?\) (char-after))
           (+ indent-offset 2))
          ((eq ?: (progn (backward-sexp)
                         (char-after)))
           (+ indent-offset (+ 2 4)))
          (t (current-column )))))

(put 'use-package 'lisp-indent-function #'my--use-package-indent-function)
```

It seems to work, but I'm unsure how robust this code is.

Better implementations are welcome!

*Edit*: following code sets up electric indent to trigger on ':', so keywords will be indented right at insertion.

```
(setq electric-indent-chars (append electric-indent-chars '(?:)))
```